# problem in changing multiviews contents on radiobuttonlists selected value

Tags: c#

I hav used a multiview in my web form in which I have used 3 view to display 3 diff forms which I want to change on radio button lists selected values... I have used 
`MultiView1.ActiveViewIndex = RadioButtonList1.SelectedValue;` this code but it's giving error as `Cannot implicitly convert type 'string' to 'int'`.

Comment: can you specify the values for your radio button list ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do if You are sure that SelectedValue is int:

```
MultiView1.ActiveViewIndex = Int32.Parse(RadioButtonList1.SelectedValue);
```

Comment: hey it works,but it just showing content of first view only..its not showing the remaining two views..

Comment: hi it worked by this code..thanks..have a great time..MultiView1.ActiveViewIndex = Convert.ToInt32(RadioButtonList1.SelectedValue);

Answer (score 0):

Use `RadioButtonList1.SelectedIndex` instead.

Although, can you guarantee the selected indices marry up with those of the `MultiView`? It may be a wiser approach to determine explicitly which `RadioButton` option has been selected and then further display the appropriate `View` using `MultiView.SetActiveView(View)`.

Comment: hi it worked by this code..thanks..have a great time..MultiView1.ActiveViewIndex = Convert.ToInt32(RadioButtonList1.SelectedValue);

Answer (score 0):

try `MultiView1.ActiveViewIndex = Convert.ToInt32(RadioButtonList1.SelectedValue);`

Comment: hey am not able to select the remaining two views..its just displaying first view only..